# Confusing Bayes Theorem Example

Tags: bayes-theorem

I'm trying to find out the probability that I have a disease given that it is in my family history so $P(disease|history)$.
If the rate of having a disease is $P(disease)=\frac{1}{1000}$ and the rate that those who have the disease have a family history of the disease is $P(history|disease)=1/10$. Then using Bayes' rule:

$P(disease|history) = \frac{P(history|disease)P(disease)}{P(history)}$

Now, I *know* that I have a family history so $P(history)=1$, right? So the right-hand side of the equation becomes $\frac{1/10000}{1}$, however this means that the probability of having the disease has gone down given that I have a family history even though the priors suggest otherwise. Have I misinterpreted the family history prior $P(history)$?

Comment: Yes, you’ve misinterpreted, P(history) is the probability that a randomly chosen person has the family history, not you in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Any statement of probability depends on some background information, call it $I$. Now we have two scenarios, we can consider background information $I_1$ which is your state of knowledge not knowing whether you have a family history of this disease, or background information $I_2=I_1\land \text{history}$.

It's certainly the case that $P(\text{history}\mid I_2)=1$ assuming $I_2$ isn't self-contradictory, but presumably the data that you refer to as $P(\text{disease})$ and $P(\text{history}\mid\text{disease})$ is $P(\text{disease}\mid I_1)$ and $P(\text{history}\mid\text{disease}\land I_1)$ respectively. Bayes law is then: $$P(\text{disease}\mid\text{history}\land I_1)=\frac{P(\text{history}\mid\text{disease}\land I_1)P(\text{disease}\mid I_1)}{P(\text{history}\mid I_1)}$$
You can't use $P(\text{history}\mid I_2)$ in place of $P(\text{history}\mid I_1)$. If you decide to use $I_2$ everywhere, then $P(\text{history}\mid\text{disease}\land I_2)= 1$ and $P(\text{disease}\mid I_2)$ is already what you want to know by definition!

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Firstly, what exactly does the caret symbol mean in your notation? Is it like logical conjunction - so $I_1 \wedge history$ means that you have the knowledge of $I_1$ and the knowledge of family history?

Comment: Yes, it is a [common symbol for logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). $I_1\land\text{history}$ means you know $I_1$ which is *all* the background knowledge you have, including facts such as kittens are fuzzy, but we usually only mention what we believe to be relevant, and $\text{history}$ which is the proposition that you have a family history of the disease. Many "absurd" and sometimes more insidious results in probability theory come down to background knowledge you know but did not formally include into the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Derek, that's some excellent insight. So I would actually need to have "the probability that someone has family's history given that they don't know they have family history" to use this version of Bayes' rule. Would this be the proper way to update the probability of having the disease given finding out family history?

Comment: Yes, you need that piece of information or something that let's you derive it. You can qualitatively see the necessity by plugging in different numbers. Indeed, you've already seen this. A very high probability for $P(\text{history}\mid I_1)$ actually *decreases* the probability that you have the disease. An analogous case would be the case of breast cancer and then adding the information that the patient is male. The other extreme is $P(\text{history}\mid I_1)=P(\text{history}\land\text{disease}\mid I_1)$ in which case everyone who has a history of the disease has the disease.